# How to keep Thunderbird (Linux) from displaying photos from GPG keys?

Tags: popup, gnupg, thunderbird

*Thunderbird 17.0.7 on Fedora Linux*

I have the Enigmail plugin installed.  Whenever I open a message that was GPG signed by someone whose GPG key includes an image, Thunderbird automatically pops up a new `eog` application to display the image.

How can I tell Thunderbird/Enigmail **not** to do this by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` and make sure the following entries are commented out:

```
list-options show-photos
verify-options show-photos
```

I think the last one is actually what you're searching for. Do note that this setting has nothing to do with Thunderbird/Enigmail, it will change the default behavior system wide.